# What does "Oracle" means in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm reading "[Diversity Creation Methods: A Survey and Categorisation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.67.2144)". There is an explanation about the Q-statistic, “Take two classifiers, fi and fj. Over a large set of testing patterns, they will exhibit certain conicident errors, and therefore a probability of error coincidence can be calculated. These are also referred to as the Oracle outputs”

Comment: Note that and oracle in ancient Greece was someone making some form of divination. See http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/神諭 (or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle for English version)

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK "Oracle" doesn't have any established meaning in ML in general. In this article it's just a synonym for an ensemble member. It's not used constantly throughout the article, so I'm guessing it's just a reference to the term used in some earlier formulation of the method discussed.

Sometimes "Oracle" stands for an imaginary source of knowledge about the *target function* - a source of training/testing samples used in some kind of intuitive proofs or 
thought experiments.